# CS50 Pset5 trouble freeing memory leak caused by malloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind, cs50

i am new to stack-overflow so bare with me

I am taking CS50 and im on Pset5(speller) My code works as intended, however when I run the check50 function my program fails Valgrind, Valgrind doesn't find the leak without adding -s.
I am sure it has something to do with freeing malloc on line 94 but still uncertain as to where i have gone wrong.

if you can assist me in resolving this issue i would much appreciate it.

link to CS50 Pset5: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/5/speller/

See below to see code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// 26 buckets as there are only 26 letters in the alphabet(regardless of starting from 1 there will still only be 26 buckets needed)
const unsigned int N = 1e6 + 9;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//Unsigned int will encode only nonnegative integers to my delcared variables
unsigned int hash_value;
unsigned int word_count;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // take the inputted hash and output a numerical value that refers to the bucket value
    hash_value = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[hash_value];

    while(cursor != 0)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor-> word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor ->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    //information pulled on hash function from:
    //https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html
    //map char array into an integer and compare those instead of the strings
    const int p = 29;
    const int m = 1e6 + 9;
    //initialise variable
    long long hash = 0;
    //start from 1 as a starting from 0 could result in a collision after calculation(if a is 0 aaa will also be 0)
    long long p_pow = 1;
    //loops through the char array
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        //iterates each char as a upper case
        char c = toupper(word[i]);
        //calculates the hash_value by subtracting the ascii value and adding back the 1 from p_pow
        hash = (hash + (c - 'A' + 1) * p_pow) % m;
        //modulo keeps integer overflow to a minimum
        p_pow = (p_pow * p) % m;
    }
    return hash;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //opens file dictionary to read the contents
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    //returns null if file couldn't be opened
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //declare variable called word;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    //While only reading strings reading through the file with fscan allocate memory for a new node
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)
    {
        //allocate the memory for a node and store the address of that node inside of n
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        //return False if memory allocation fails, do this by checking if n is equal to NULL(this tells if this is the first in the list)
        if (n == NULL)
        {
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
         //pointer to the destination array where the string is to be copied
         strcpy(n->word, word);
         //increment word count based on number of words being pulled from the dictionary
         word_count++;
         //after hashing the word store the number value in a variable
         hash_value = hash(word);
         //set the pointer of the new node to the front of the table
         n->next = table[hash_value];

         //
         table[hash_value] = n;
        }

    }
    //free up system resources that are using the file once finished
    fclose(file);
    return true;

}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // return the size of dictionary
    if(word_count > 0)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // to free memory used by malloc
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
            if (cursor == NULL)
            {
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//////////
//Load  which responsible for loading the data into a hash table
//Hash  take a word run a hash function returning a number that corrisponds to that word
//Size  which returns how many words are in the dictionary
//Check  which answers whether the word is in the dictionary or not
//Unload  free the memory that you allocated
```

running Check50 results below

:( program is free of memory errors

valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.:

```
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpgldh6b_g -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 94)
```

if you would like more information feel free to ask.

i have tried searching multiple other forums for ways to free malloc and looking to ensure i have closed all files opened.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre]. How are you using the functions you currently show? Where's your simple testing `main` function?

Comment: The loop in `unload` returns after freeing the first chain of nodes. You should remove that code. It also doesn't make much sense to return true or false there. There's no success or failure case in that function.

Comment: OT Hint: When adding words (from a dictionary presumed to be sorted), the first word in any _chain_ at a given hash value will be the "largest value" word in the list... When searching along that linked list for, for example, "dogg", you can stop the search (not found) when you encounter "cat" (or whatever word would _preceed_ the absent "dogg". No need to keep comparing against "bat" and "aardvark"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of unload() should be

```
void unload(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
 }
```

1. The function should return nothing instead of bool according to your logic.
2. The return inside of while loop terminate the for loop in its first iteration. Then the elements[1...n - 1] of table aren't freed, causing the memory leak.

Comment: thank you for replying comprehensively, this was my initial thought but due to the distribution code given by CS50 unload must remain a bool function, however you did help me find the solution by informing me of the shortfall of my for loop :)